# Receive touchesMoved when touch began in the super view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

In iOS, I would like to receive `touchesMoved` events in a subview even when the touch began i the super view! Ideally, I would also like to receive `touchesBegan` when the moving finger reaches the subview.

What is the best way to achieve this? 
I guess I could override `touchesMoved:withEvent:` in the superview, do a hit-test and then call the subview, but is there a better solution? (I have tried to resign first responder in the superview but that did not help)

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution? I have a similar problem where a touch is fired and a new `UIView` is added on the screen. I need to capture the `touchesMoved` event in the new `UIView` without releasing the fingers from the screen... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll be working on this exact same problem later this weekend. If I figure out a solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this exact same problem today, and I just did.

Say, you have the following -- this is an abstract description of exactly my case:

- Main view containing a button and a sub view
- When touches begin on the main view you want to receive the touch events on the sub view
- One exception is that button: if you tap the button in the main view, then the button should handle that

The solution is to override the `-hitTest:withEvent:` method. The purpose of that method is to return the view that should handle the touches.

You have two options: override it in the sub view or override it in the main view. If you want ALL touches to be handled by the sub view, you can just have the `-hitTest:withEvent` on the sub view return `self` and be done with it. In my case I still needed the button on the main view to have its own touch detection, so my fix was to override the `-hitTest:withEvent:` method on the main view instead, as follows:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myButton.frame, point))
    {
        return self.myButton;
    }
    else
    {
        return self.mySubView;
    }
}
```

This works like an absolute charm! Hope this works for you as well :-)

You should of course modify the details inside `-hitTest:withEvent:` to suit your specific needs -- maybe you want to limit this override to a specific region or a specific set of controls -- but the point is that the answer to the main question on this thread lies in the override of this `-hitTest:withEvent:` method.

Erik